# How to call a multi sourced drawable?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-drawable

Recently I started learning Android Studio. I have a problem
when I added images directly in drawable folder I could easily called using R.drawable as shown in the picture:

[image: screenshot 1]

But when I would to call a multi sourced drawable I could not. It said "Unknown class". 
 [image: screenshot 2]

Comment: How about doing
int flag = R.drawable.za;

Comment: Avoid posting code as image, use proper capitalization.